# i386 x86_64 combined architecture?

Tags: macos, 32bit-64bit

I am coming from windows development. I have known that a binary can either be a 32bit or 64bit. But not both. And also that on a 64bit platform I can run 32bit binary but not viceversa.

In mac I am seeing a combined architecture like i386 x86_64 which is a bit of surprise for me. Why and when exactly do we target an app on mac osx for this architecture , what is the benefit of this ? why not a 32bit only which per my understanding of windows can run on 32bit as well as 64bit ?

Comment: Also, now this has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode. Really. No-wait for it!-thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that the code is compiled for a "mixed" architecture - it's just that [it's compiled for multiple ones.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary#Mach-O_and_Mac_OS_X)

The reason for compiling it for both 32 and 64 bit is that 64-bit programs generally perform better on a 64-bit architecture (most modern Macs) than 32-bit ones.

Comment: Same link I was about to post. +1

Comment: So If I understand you correctly it will generate two binaries a 32bit and a 64 bit. So if that's the case I will have to ship 2 production versions one for 32bit and other for 64bit right ?

Comment: @Ahmed Did you even *read* the link? That's just bad manners.

Comment: @Ahmed No, you don't have to, since it'll be dumped into one fat file. Yes, it seems you really didn't care to visit that link...

Comment: @H2CO3 I went to that link and section you linked was  Mach-O and Mac OS X to be honest I did not get that at all.. :(

Comment: I guess the whole page is important to be read,earlier I just saw the linked section only. Sorry and thanks about the feedback